# Password Change Required response from RESTful Token Service

Tags: security, authentication, rest, restful-authentication

I am trying to determine the best way to enforce password expiration rules in my solution.

The server-side exposes a REST API for operations with a custom active Security Token Service (of sorts).  Client applications pass user credentials to a REST endpoint where the user is authenticated on the server.  The response includes a custom security token representing the user which is then passed to other API methods so the call can be authorized.  The server is stateless and does not maintain any reference to the identity or claims information (i.e. session-less).

We have password expiration rules that are enforced by the server.  So, when authenticating a user, it is possible that their password has expired.  I need to communicate this to the client so they can do whatever is needed to have the user change their password. (There is another REST endpoint for changing the password on the server.)

**Questions**

1. It seems to me that authenticating a user with an expired password should fail. However, I need to know the identity of the user changing the password when making the second API call, so should I go ahead and return a token even when the password has expired?
2. How should I inform the client that a password change is required?  I thought about including this as a claim in the token, but that would require me to reissue a new token after the password has been changed or modify the original token which isn't allowed.  My other thought was a custom HTTP Status Code that I would correspond to meaning Password Change Required.
3. The answer to this question probably depends on the previous two, but I don't want to authorize a user that has an expired password if the token is passed to any other APIs (besides changing the password).  What's the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why don't you just have the password changing endpoint accept everything it needs to do the job (presumably, userid, old password, and new password) as parameters and not need a session?

Comment: You have me scratching my head. First, as I said in the post, I don't have a session so not sure what you are getting at there. Second, the change password endpoint DOES accept everything it needs.  Finally, and most importantly, the questions have nothing to do with performing a password change.  I am asking about authenticating a user that requires a password change and how to communicate that state to the client in a way that it consistent with token-based security.

Comment: sorry for the term "session". I meant what you called "custom security token". All I meant to say is that the client doesn't receive one of those until they've changed their password (seems to answer Q#1 and Q#3), and they shouldn't need one in order to change their password, so where's the problem? As for how to tell the client they need to change their password (Q#2), that's whatever you want to make it (special HTTP status, something in a JSON body, custom header, etc...).

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense.  The reason I have considered responding with a token is so the client can pass the identity of the current user with the password change request so the user can be authorized. For instance, only the user or their supervisor may change their password.

Comment: I think that changing one's own password and a supervisor changing someone's password are two conceptually different things and should be handled by two different URLs. The former doesn't want you to be authenticated already and it needs both old & new passwords. The latter needs you to be authenticated already (as the supervisor or superuser) and doesn't accept for the old password. The former doesn't expect to see the custom security token. The latter must see it and validate it.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that I can't mark the question answered when there are only comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what I ended up doing (certainly not the be-all-end-all solution) is having my Authenticate endpoint return an AuthenticationResultCode enumerated value in the response in lieu of a simple pass/fail boolean.  Possible values for the enumeration include:

- ValidCredentials - the user was authenticated and the AuthenticationToken is included in the response.
- InvalidCredentials - the user was not authenticated
- CredentialsExpired - the user was authenticated but their password has expired. I have yet to determine if the AuthToken will be included with this result.
- NoCredentials - no credentials were provided to the request

Now the client has more information about the result than a pass/fail value (which I really never checked anyway) and I can take the appropriate action in response such as automatically displaying the ChangePasswordDialog when CredentialsExpired is received.

Like I said, still working out whether or not I should still send the token when the credentials are expired because I don't want to be able to authorize a user if their credentials are expired but they've already been authenticated once and I don't think it makes sense to re-authenticate after changing the password (after all, I have to be authenticated so I can change the password in the first place).  Maybe just a simple IsLocked or IsExpired property on the client will suffice...

Comment: it would be nice if you could update your answer after your experience on that